# What are languages whose name contains the word for "language"?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages

For example, imagine the name of our language was "Englishlanguage", and we had to always say "I speak Englishlanguage" or "She's a native Englishlanguage speaker". The closest I can think of is 日本語 "nihon-go" or the name for Japanese, where the "go" means "word", but this isn't exactly what I mean. I'm wondering if there is any language that contains the word for "language" or "tongue" or similar, in the native name for the language. For example, are there any cultures who name their language after themselves (e.g. "I speak LanguageoftheAngles but she speaks LanguageoftheFranks")

Comment: There are many such languages so the answer will simply be a long list.

Comment: I would say that *"English"*, meaning *"English language"*, is just a contraction. Only if the context allows, one uses the contracted form.

Comment: It is really the case in most if not all languages, but "language" is usually elided, although in some cases less often than in English.  The languages where it is always explicitly there are those that have not a separate word but a specific suffix.  However that suffix cannot stand alone,  it does not mean "language" or anything else.  Examples are Turkic -çe/-ça/-ce/-ca.  Armenian -eren is an edge case because you can still say *angleren lezu* (English language) or *angleren bar* (English word).

Comment: There are also Fala, Tok Pisin, Papamiento, Lingua Franca and the like.

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept, as all of them are valid answers to the question. The main question was simply a binary one, "Do such languages exist?", and all answers give useful information relating to that.

Comment: One more: the name of the Brazilian language *nheengatu* means "the good language" (nheen-).

Comment: @bytebuster and A.M. Bittlingmaier. If 'English' were a 'contracted' (or 'elliptical') version of 'English language' (or 'Deutsch' of 'deutsche Sprache', etc.), it should be possible to use the uncontracted versions as subjects, objects or P complements in sentences like '*English language is our modern koiné', '*Most young people speaks English language', '*The vocabulary of English language is huge' (also: '*Deutsche Sprache ist schwer', '*Ich habe deutsche Sprache gelernt', '*Sprechen Sie bitte nur auf deutsche Sprache', etc.). Of course, it is not, ergo 'English', etc. are NOT elliptical.

Comment: @bytebuster Sorry, but I do not understand your remark.

Comment: @bytebuster Sorry, I had not seen your remark. My point above is that, in cases of ellision, the non-elliptical phrase may be redundant in context, but is never ungrammatical. If 'English', 'Deutsch' were elliptical versions of 'English language', 'deutsche Sprache', 'English' or 'deutsche' would be ADJECTIVES and recovering the elided N's 'language', 'Sprache' would yield, possibly redundant, but grammatical sentences. Since, on the contrary, the result is bad, 'English' is NOT an ellipsis of 'English language' (and an Adj.), but a N (with special properties) that names the English language.

Answer (score 9):

The (Equadorian) Quechua name for the language is *Runa Shimi* meaning "Language of the People". All of the Saami terms for the languages (e.g. North Saami, Lule Saami etc) include the word "language", such as *Davvisáme**giella***. 
The Lushootseed name for the language, dxʷləšucid, means "language of the south" and contains a suffix -*ucid* which means "language" and "mouth" (there isn't really a separate word "language").

Comment: Similarly, _Lushootseed_ is the English spelling of _dxʷləšúcid_, which means _our language_. The -ucid suffix is first person plural possessive, and the dxʷ- prefix marks a nominalization; together they combine to indicate a language. The root is ləš, which designates the Salish Sea. So _dxʷləšúcid_ is the name for the common language in that area; there are also grammatical means to indicate dialects: _qaǰət-əb_ 'be a Skagit (person), _qqaǰətəb_ (with initial C- reduplication) 'speak Skagit'; _duhubš-əb_ 'be a Snohomish (person), _dduhubš-əb_ 'speak Snohomish'.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis of *-ucid*. The 1p possessive suffix is -čəɬ (p. 85 of the textbook if you have it) e.g. *ʔalʔalčəɬ* "our house". A 1pl poss. interpretation would also not make sense given *pastəducid* "English", *dxʷləbəyʔucid* "Lummi. It is true though that at least taqʷšəblu rendered "Skagit (language)" as bare *sqaǰət*.

Comment: You're correct; it's not a pronoun. I was confusing it with a different morpheme. The dictionary says that dxʷ-  and -ucid "constitute 'language'".

Comment: Also "suomenkieli" for Finnish (but they do not put -kieli on the end of all names of languages I don't think. But the Ainu do: "Ainu itak" for Ainu, "Hure sisam itak" for Russian etc).
As for exonyms, in English we have the name "Western Desert Language", "British Sign Language" etc. etc. There are too many to list

Answer (score 6):

Bahasa Melayu (Malay); Bahasa Indonesia (Indonesian).

Comment: Indonesian often refers as "Bahasa" for their language (Bahasa = language), I noticed a lot of Indonesian people think that "Bahasa" is the name for Indonesian/Bahasa Indonesia.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are even endonyms like [Fala](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fala_language) that simply mean *language*/*speech* with no further qualification.

Tok Pisin, Papiamento, Lingua Franca etc are other examples.

(*Tok* in *Tok Pisin* is from English *talk*.  *Papia* in *Papiamento* is from *papear* (*to chat*).  *lingua* in *Lingua Franca* is from *lingua* (*language*, *tongue*).)

There is also the Turkic suffix [-ce/-ca/-çe/-ça](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ce#Turkish), which is used explicitly for languages but cannot stand alone.

Affectionately Yiddish is often referred to as [מאַמע־לשון](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%9E%D7%A2%D6%BE%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F) (*mother tongue*), if you search you can also find German dialects and languages referred to with *Muttersprache*, *Mottersproch*, *Muddasprach*, *Muttersprak* etc.

Comment: Like Fala (which can also be used to refer to some other languages/languages' dialects on the peninsula), Asturian is also known as *llingua*

Comment: Could you explain the roots, in papamiento, etc? Lingua franca can be many languages, but that's true that one language bears this name, it's confusing, because one never knows if people refers as a group of languages, or as the pidgin.

Comment: @Quidam Updated

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer [Toki Pona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona)

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer [Kiswahili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swahili_language) is questionable because the it means 'language of the Swahili' (the 'ki' meaning something near to 'language of', but Swahili is what is used in English to mean the language. Wait...this isn't ELU, so it works!

Comment: A similar suffix is Irish _-(a)is_, which is also used exclusively to form names of languages, corresponding to _-(e)ach_ used to form generic national adjectives (e.g., _turcach_ ‘Turkish [generic adjective]’, turcais_ ‘Turkish language’).

Comment: In Tok Pisin, is "Tok" used as the noun "language"? Ki-swahili doesn't mean "Swahili language", it means "the manner of the Swahili", conventionally assigned to language, but used for other purposes e.g. "cooking in the Swahili way". The prefix lu/ru (Luganda etc) is closer to identifying just "language", since cl. 11 doesn't have the same general "manner" semantics that cl. 7 has (it's based on the word *lulimi* "tongue/language".

Comment: *Volapük* ‘world-speech’

Answer (score 4):

Chinese language, 漢語 han4 yü3. Literally means "Han [Chinese] language". The Vietnamese name for the Vietnamese language, Tiếng Việt (㗂越), also means "Viet language" literally.

Answer (score 3):

In Lithuanian, the name of a language is the genitve plural of its speaker + the word "language": eg. *lietuvių kalba* 'Lithuanian language(lit. language of the lithuanians)', *anglų kalba* 'English language', *kinų kalba* 'Chinese language'. However, the word "kalba" **maybe omitted** if the context allows.

In sentences like "I speak XXX language", the forms above are not used, they use an adverb instead. For instance, *Aš kalbu lietuviškai* 'I speak Lithuanian(lit. I speak in the lithuanians' way)'

Answer (score 3):

An example from an Australian Aboriginal language is [Murriny-patha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murrinh-patha_language), which might be glossed as *language good*.

Also referring to language families but not languages, we have examples like *Langue d'oc* vs *Langue d'oïl* (referring to the language groups' respective words for "yes").

Comment: Brazilian native language *nheengatu* is also "good language".  They should be friends.

Answer (score 2):

Classical Nahuatl speakers refer to their language as *Nahuatlahtolli*, "Nahuatl language", from *Nahuatl* + *tlahtolli*. However they add *tlahtolli* to any other language, so "I speak English and German" is translated *Nitlahtoa Inglatlahtolli ihuan Teutontlahtolli*. In modern Nahuatl *tlahtolli* may be omitted: *Nitlahtoa zan tepitzin Nahuatl*, "I only speak a little Nahuatl".

Answer (score 2):

The Sumerian language is known in Sumerian as [eme-gir15, which means "native tongue"](http://cdli.ucla.edu/pubs/cdlp/cdlp0002_20160104.pdf) (Foxvog, Daniel A., Introduction to 
Sumerian Grammar. 2016 January 4, p. 21).

The Japanese language is known natively as [日本語 ("Nihongo")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language), which literally means "sun rise language", or, more loosely, "language of the rising sun".

Comment: More like "language of Sun-Origin", where Sun-Origin is a singular proper noun and the name of the country.  (that is, it's [[nihon]go] not [[ni][hon][go]]).

Answer (score 1):

The native name for **Latin** is *Lingua Latina* "Latin language". The adjective *latinus* is not only used for the Latin language, but also for people and things coming from the region of Latium (where the Latin language was originally spoken).

Comment: Isn't this equally true for English, though?